# Oracle APEX and searching IG on a numeric field

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

It appears that APEX Interactive Grid cannot be searched on numeric fields. Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#P40_NEW_1").keyup(function(){
    var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
    $.each($(".a-GV-table tr"), function() {
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) === -1)
           $(this).hide();
        else
           $(this).show();                
    });
});
```

> Craete a page item for search.
>
> Then Create a Dynamic Action on Keypress and Put this code.